# How to append multiple files into single file and then mail them?

Tags: shell-script

```
if [[ unix = unix ]]
then
echo "they are same" > a.txt
else 
echo "they are not same" > b.txt
a.txt>>b.txt>c.txt
mail -s "comparison" abc@gmail.com < /home/c.txt
```

I just want the body of the mail to state either they are same or they are not same, but I'm not getting the expected output.

One of the files, either `a.txt` or `b.txt` is reported as `command not found`.

Comment: what is it that you are expecting `a.txt>>b.txt>c.txt` to do?  are you trying to concatenate `a.txt` and `b.txt` into a new file called `c.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

*It's not clear to me what your intent is in your script but I will answer your primary question from the title, "How to append multiple files into single file?"...*

Redirection operators (`>`, `>>`, `<`, etc.) don't work on files alone. They work with the inputs and outputs of commands. `foo > bar` doesn't mean "overwrite `bar` with the contents of `foo`". It means "run the command `foo` and overwrite `bar` with its output". And `foo >> bar` means "run the command `foo` and append its output to the current contents of `bar`". Also, you can't chain these. `foo > bar > baz` doesn't mean anything.

If you want to *concatentate* the contents of multiple files and append the result to another file then you'll want to use `>>` operator in conjunction with the `cat` command:

```
cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

So, using your filenames, to append both `a.txt` and `b.txt` to `c.txt` you can do this:

```
cat a.txt b.txt >> c.txt
```

And since you asked about something similar in a comment, these two commands are equivalent to the single line version:

```
cat a.txt >> c.txt
cat b.txt >> c.txt
```

Comment: Thanks much, its working out for me...But i have a small query..If i want the content of the file to be appended to the next line of the file while doing multiple append, pls let me know how to do that..right now im getting multiple append output in the same line...

Comment: `>` overwrites a file, `>>` appends to it.

Comment: @VimalKumar Not sure I understand your question. Are you saying that when you append a file containing `banana` to a file containing `apple` then the result is `applebanana` (i.e. a single line)? This would only happen if the file you're appending to did not have a newline at the end which is not common. How did the file you are appending to get generated?

Comment: yes thats how im getting the output as applebannana, but i need the output as apple in one line and bannana in second line seperately

Comment: You need to figure out why it's getting created without the newline. Nothing I discuss in my answer is related to that. But as a workaround you could do `echo "" >> file` to append a newline before you append the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That can be simplified a lot:

```
compare='not '
[[ unix = unix ]] && compare=''
echo "they are ${compare}the same" | mail -s "comparison" abc@gmail.com
```

This sets `not` (with a trailing space) as the default value for variable `$compare`.  if the two strings are the same, it sets $compare to be an empty string.  Then prints the message with the embedded variable and mails it.

Comment: if [[ unix = unix ]]
then
echo "they are same" > a.txt
else 
echo "they are not same" > b.txt
if [[ db = db ]]
then
echo "they are same" > c.txt
else 
echo "they are not same" > d.txt
cat a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt >> e.txt
mail -s "comparison" abc@gmail.com < /home/e.txt

im getting the output as 
they are same they are same..
but i want the output as
they are same
they are same

Comment: what? that makes no more sense than your original script.  apart from the faulty use of redirection operators, you're still trying to use 3 temporary files when none are actually needed - all you need is one variable.